# DragonBoard 410c HDMI cable not being detected in my Dell Laptop

Tags: iot, dragonboard

I am trying to use android Os that comes default with the DragonBoard 410c. To see the Android OS load and work on it I tried connecting a HDMI cable from board to Laptop(Windows 7/8, Dell inspiron) but even after several minutes I do not see any detection of the board on my laptop.

1.Connected HDMI to DragonBoard and Laptop.
2.Connected power adapter to board.
3. User-1 LED light glows intermittently on the board.
Board not detected even after several minutes, so i tried to goto control panel and add device but no luck there also.

Not sure if the HDMI cable has the problem or the board. Please help on troubleshooting and solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the notebook's HDMI slot is built for video output purpose. And you're trying to use it as a video input.

You need to use a device that has an HDMI input slot, such as a TV or PC Monitor.

You can also try to use a HDMI->VGA converter, to get a wide range of compatible Computer Monitors, but beware that I only manage it to work in the forth brand of converter. (The other aren't broken, just didn't work with the DB410C).

For futhermore, I recommend to use SSH.